# 404 - basic spring rest failing and showing 404 error

Tags: rest

trying a spring rest application and getting 404, am not able to figure out the problem, the server console shows nothing about the problem, below is the code

```
there were many posts for this problem, i checked them did modifications also, none worked
could any body please give the solution to this.Thank you
```

this is controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class SpringServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getGreeting(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result="Hello "+name;
        System.out.println("in the controller");
        return result;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>springRest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <context-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

        <listener>
           <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
           </listener-class>
        </listener> 


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

this is rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.vasu.springRest.controller.*" />




</beans>
```

Comment: you can try adding @ResponseBody over getGreeting method

Comment: @user3470953,--- thanks for responding  no change, its the same error, below are the 2 lines are shown on the server console            org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springRest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'

Comment: use "/" in mapping; <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: changed the url pattern to "/" , no its not working .......thank you

Comment: http://localhost:8082/springRest/service/basu --- is the url I am trying with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.vasu.springRest.controller" />
```